# How to run DB2 compound SQL statements using Java

Tags: java, db2

I am trying to run compound DB2 statements (set of SQL statements) from Java program. Please help with some suggestions. Below is the sample program I tried but not working. Basically, multiple SQL statements are not being allowed in CallableStatement.

---

```
Connection dbConnection = null;
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

try {
    dbConnection = getDBConnection();
    dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

    String sql= "DECLARE BEGIN " + 
        "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EmpId, EmpName) VALUES (1, 'Name1'); " +
        "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EmpId, EmpName) VALUES (2, 'Name2'); " +
        "END";

    callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(sql);

    callableStatement.executeUpdate();

    dbConnection.commit();


} catch (SQLException e) {
    dbConnection.rollback();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

} finally {

    if (callableStatement != null) {
        callableStatement.close();
    }
    if (dbConnection != null) {
        dbConnection.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dbConnection = getDBConnection();
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

String sql= "BEGIN " + 
    "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EmpId, EmpName) VALUES (1, 'Name1'); " +
    "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EmpId, EmpName) VALUES (2, 'Name2'); " +
    "END";

callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(sql);
callableStatement.execute();
```

Provide a full error message / stack trace, your Db2 version and platform, if it doesn't work.